# Find all the related nodes which are not related to any other node via a different relationship

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to find all the related nodes for an item (via the found_for relationship) which are not related to any other item (via a found_for_term relationship) -

```
START n=node(8402) MATCH n<-[:friend]-(m) WHERE not(m-[:relative]->()) RETURN m.id;
```

This works on 1.9.2 but throws an 'Invalid Query' error on 1.8.1.

I'm using the Neo4j Addon on Heroku which is on 1.8.1 (and they currently don't intend to upgrade to 1.9.2)

Can you help me re-factor the query and explain why it fails on 1.8.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use the other slow option with an option relationship:

```
START n=node(8402) 
MATCH n<-[:friend]-(m) 
WITH m
MATCH m-[r?:relative]->()
WHERE r IS NULL 
RETURN m.id;
```

Better still, upgrade to 1.9 or 2.0 using graphenedb.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `WHERE NOT` does not support anonymous nodes in its path in 1.8.1. A workaround for this is:

```
START n=node(8402), x=node(*) 
MATCH n<-[:friend]-(m) 
WHERE not( (m)-->(x) ) 
RETURN m.id;
```

However this query will be slow as `node(*)` touches all nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Stefan! I'm a neo4j noob, but I'm guessing Michael's version would have better performance?